# Why when I run my code in Cobol, the error is appear but it say nothing?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I have couple errors when I test my code with Cobol:
1: car1.cbl:44: libcob: READ/START not allowed (STATUS = 47) File : 'D:\cobol\CARFILE.TXT'
2:  [you can see the error but it show nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy2Zz.png)

I think maybe because of my app so I tried to reinstall and when i run the same code it show error like the picture. Please help. thanks

Comment: Please paste you code as text instead of an image.

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk the image is of the IDE with the code that might help determine what the error is.

Comment: @eglease, Ah ok. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: I'm curious to see what information is under the Compiler tab at the bottom.

Comment: There should be no image at all, just the code and the error, as text, here.

Answer (score 3):

`STATUS = 47` means that a file operation was attempted after the file was closed. In this case, a `READ` statement.

After the first `READ`, the file is closed at line 57. The next `READ` causes the error.

Remove the `CLOSE` statement at line 57.

```
        CLOSE CAR-FILE-IN.
```

This will keep the file open until end-of-file. The file will be closed by the `CLOSE` statement at line 36.